# CSS Firefox and Chrome different height output

Tags: css

I did read other threads having a similar problem, but nothing I read there helped. This is my problem for this website: http://bit.ly/1gmeHtu

Look at this picture the blue part with the magnifying glass:

[image: Firefox Browser]

In Chrome it looks perfect. However, when I fix that by inserting a height css, then it gets fixed in Firefox, but this happens in Chrome:

[image]

So I tried changing font-size for the text there too, but that didn't work either. I tried some padding stuff, didn't work. And now here I am for help.

Here is the code of the search box:

```
                 <div class="test_line_1"><?php echo stripslashes(get_option('Pricerr_main_how_it_works_line1')) ?></div>
             <div class="test_line_2"><?php echo stripslashes(get_option('Pricerr_main_how_it_works_line2')) ?></div>
             <div class="test_line_3">

                <form method="get" action="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') ?>">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_advanced_search_id') ?>" name="page_id" />
                    <input type="text" name="term1" value="" id="big_search_m" placeholder="<?php _e('Search for services here...','PricerrTheme') ?>" /> 
                    <input type="image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/search_sel.png" id="search_magnifier" />
                </form>

             </div>


        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS for all 3 of these elements:

```
.test_line_3 {
    margin: 40px auto auto;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 8px solid rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.8);
}

#big_search_m {
    padding: 12px;
    border: 0px none;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
}

#search_magnifier {
    float: left;
}
```

How do I fix this?

EDIT: The code of the search box Without the PHP in it:

```
<div class="test_line_1"></div>
             <div class="test_line_2"></div>
             <div class="test_line_3">

                <form method="get">
                <input type="hidden" name="page_id" />
                    <input type="text" name="term1" value="" id="big_search_m" /> 
                    <input type="image" id="search_magnifier" />
                </form>

             </div>


        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In your HTML you have `id="big_search_m2"` but in your CSS you have `#big_search_m`, same for `#search_magnifier`

Comment: Apologies Lauromine. I had put the HTML for the little search box in the upper left corner of the site by mistake. Now it's been updated. Now it's the correct HTML for the CSS.

Comment: I cannot work in PHP-cluttered HTML. Create a proper fiddle demonstrating your problem and remove all php code.

Comment: Not solving but you can remove the `float: left` of `#big_search_m` and replace the `float: left`of `#search_magnifier` by `float: right`

Comment: Okay Lauromine. I guess I'll do that in the end maybe. I'll leave it as it is for now though. Thank you.

Comment: connexo - I'll try to do what you said. I'm not very experienced with this stuff. I'll try to clean up the code for you. But creating a propre fiddle demonstrating my problem, I wouldn't know how to do that.

Comment: Okay connexo, I did clean up the code of the php. I hope I did it correctly.

Comment: In css try setting both `test_line_2` and `test_line_3` to `height: 100%` so that they will both fill up the height of `test_line_1`

Comment: I tried it Kevin Ni, but it didn't work. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Something I just noticed, your fonts are different inside each search bar. That might be the cause of what you're seeing. So make sure you set a standard font, font size, and/or line height. That might help. And since you said you're not experienced, you should learn how to use the "Inspect Element" tool - it helps a ton, and would probably help in fixing your issue as well!

Comment: That I do Kevin, I use inspect element a lot. I'm just not very experienced in php and fiddle that connexo asked me to do. For CSS and HTML, I did that whole website, but sometimes, like the search bar problem, I get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in both browsers with defined height.

```css
.test_line_3 {
  margin: 40px auto auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 8px solid rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.8);
}
#big_search_m {
  padding: 12px;
  border: 0px none;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  height: 52px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: yellow;
}
#search_magnifier {
  float: left;
  background: url("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1");
  height: 52px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test_line_1"></div>
<div class="test_line_2"></div>
<div class="test_line_3">

  <form method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="page_id" />
    <input type="text" name="term1" value="" id="big_search_m" />
    <input type="image" id="search_magnifier" />
  </form>

</div>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you emmanuel. That fixed it! Thank you very much. In fact, only the two height:# codes and the box-sizing: border-box; were required, and it's fixed. I never knew about this box-sizing: border-box; css code. Thanks a lot!